# what is the difference between "at the weekends" and at weekends?

Tags: definite-article

Do these sentences have the same meaning?

"I go shopping at the weekends."

"I go shopping at weekends."

Answer (score 1):

"At the weekends" implies a little more that you're going shopping *every* weekend. It's not as strong as directly saying, "I go shopping every weekend", but it has this underlying implication. You might say, you're going shopping not on *some* weekends, but on *the* weekends as a category.

In contrast, "at weekends" implies more that if you go shopping, you do it on the weekend and not on any other day of the week. You don't necessarily go shopping *every* weekend, but if you go, it's probably on the weekend.

This is no clear, strong distinction that's obeyed every time, but more of an implied tendency.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, certainly is colloquial use, and mean the same thing.

The [Cambridge Dictionary lists](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/weekend) "*at weekends*" as UK and "*on (the) weekends*" as US.

See also this related question:
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75466/at-on-the-weekends